# what is the best way for create a realistic ribbon with three.js

Tags: three.js

I'v tried with a CatmullRomCurve3 and TubeBufferGeometry (with 2 faces) but the curve is not realist.

```
            var path = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
            new THREE.Vector3( -50, 0, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 50 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( 0, 50, 50 ),
              ] );

            tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( path, segments, largeur, 2, params.closed );
```

[image: ribbon]

Is there another method or can i rotation a Vector3

I want to do something like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the mesh line approach from the official examples directory? https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat.html

Comment: I've the same problem with this method

Comment: @Kriegwolf have you ever figured out a way to do it?